# Dynamic Update with composite id hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, composite-id

In hibernate, if dynamic-update is enabled, while updating the object it generates query for only modified columns

Consider a class with composite-id using components. Composite-id saveOrupdate the object. If the given key is not is DB, it adds otherwise updates the object

Now what I want is how can I merge this 2 features? For example I have a class with 3 attributes age, salary, address and a composite key id and name.

For key "1-Mohan" I already have entries for age =22, salary =30000, address =XXX. Now I want to only update its salary to 40000. When I create a new instance with the key "1-mohan" and setting only salary = 4000 and persists. Now the record fill null values for age and address since dynamic-update only happens for object fetched from DB.

Is any way there to retain its existing values unchanged and update only the given attribute without fetching the object from DB??

Answer (score 0):

Setting `dynamic-update` to  `true` will not set `null` values for other fields, instead it will just update the fields which are modified.

For example in your example the query generated by hibernate will be like:

```
 UPDATE USER_TABLE SET SALARY=? 
    WHERE ID=? AND NAME=?
```

So it is not going to set `null` values for other fields.

**Update:**

Now based on your explanation in comments the issue has no relation with `dynamic-update`.

What you have to do is first use `Session.get` to get your object based on the `composite-id`. Now your object will have all fields set. Now update the `salary` field and then call `saveOrUpdate` method.

If the `dynamic-update` is `false` then hibernate will generate `update` query by including all the fields.

```
 UPDATE USER_TABLE SET SALARY=?, AGE=?, ADDRESS=? 
    WHERE ID=? AND NAME=?
```

If the `dynamic-update` is `true` then hibernate will generate `update` query by including only the `salary` field as mentioned in my answer.

```
 UPDATE USER_TABLE SET SALARY=? 
    WHERE ID=? AND NAME=?
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But my question is when we use dynamic-update with composite-id. In that case we only create new object and give for saveOrupdate

Comment: @MohanRajB, I am not clear what you are trying to say, if you are creating new object and just setting the `salery` field then hibernate will set `null` values for all other properties even if you do not have `dymaic-update` then there is no issue right?

Comment: yes you are right. I am creating new object with one key and in DB there exists an object already with same key (composite-id). Now since it is using composite-id, it will call saveorupdate and update the existing row which will make all other fields as null other than the field I have updated. I want those field  that does not change to retain their original value during this update

Comment: Yes. But please see my question "Is any way there to retain its existing values unchanged and update only the given attribute without fetching the object from DB??"

Comment: @MohanRajB, if you want to update only few fields then you should go for HQL or native SQL where you can specify the exact query that should be run against DB. If you try to save/update the complete entity without setting some fields, then you are telling hibernate that you want to set those fields to `null` so it is not possible to save the entity by preserving previous state for some fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61743/discussion-between-mohan-raj-b-and-chaitanya).